# Error happening when no value

Tags: c#

I created a program that requires the user to input a value into a text box. I'm trying to have the text box default to `0` if there is no value put in by the user.

Currently, if there is no value put in and the calculation is attempted I get the error "input string was not in a correct format" error.

This is what I have:

`cexp = int.Parse(currentexp.Text);`
`currentexp.Text = "";`

I want to try to do something like this:

`if (currentexp.text == "")`
`set cexp = 0`

So if the text box is empty then I want to set the variable cexp to equal 0.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** You can use `Conditional operator` for setting the default value.

```
int cexp=(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentexp.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(currentexp.text) : 0;
```

**Solution 2:** You can use `int.TryParse()` to perform the validation.

```
int cexp;
if(int.TryParse(currentexp.Text,out cexp))
{
//conversion successfull do some thing here
}
else
{
//conversion failed so do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ` and conditional operator:

```
cexp = !currentexp.Text.All(char.IsDigit) ||
       !currentexp.Text.Any() ? 0 :  int.Parse(currentexp.Text)
```

This will set `cexp` to zero when `currentexp.Text` contains one or more *non-digit* characters.

Comment: Yeah it still needs at least 1 character though. I'm trying to get it to where the user doesn't have to enter anything at all and it will just set it cexp = 0

Comment: @Advancin you right I just noticed that.anyway you can add another condition to check that I updated my answer.I think you should still use All method to check whether all characters are digit,it will avoid the exception when input is invalid.Or you can use int.TryParse

Answer (score 0):

It might be good to use `int.TryParse` for this, since the user is entering in data.

```
int cexp = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out cexp))
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("An invalid entry was entered, do you want to use 0 instead?", 
                                 "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //do stuff to continue here
        //cexp will already be 0
    }
    else
    {
        //don't continue, they wanted to try again
    }
}
```

This will default the value of `cexp` to 0, and if the user enters something invalid it will warn them (and still keep `cexp` at 0). If they put in a correct value, then `cexp` will be updated to what the user entered.

If you don't want to warn the user or anything, and just want to continue, this will work.

```
int cexp = 0; //default to 0
int.TryParse(currentexptextBox1.Text, out cexp); //try to get a number, if it fails, cexp will still be 0
```

Comment: This works well, but is there a way to default to 0 even if they enter nothing?

With the prompt they still need to enter something to get the calculation done.

Comment: You can ask the user to continue or not, I updated the above code.

Comment: Yea this is working, but I just want to be able to execute with nothing in the text box. If the user enters nothing the program should continue with the assumption the user meant "0"

This alerts the user to "hey you didn't put anything in there" but sometimes there isn't anything to put so having to put 0 is a bit annoying.

Comment: Ahh, ok then you don't even need the `MessageBox` then. `int.TryParse` will take whatever the user entered, and update `cexp` accordingly. If it fails (user put in nothing, or typed some letters) then it'll leave `cexp` at 0.